# Repeating Background Fixed Distance

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, background-image

I want to repeat my background image in CSS with a margin, so there is a **fixed** distance between the images. I have tried to solve it using svg, but it does not show any background image at all if I do it like that:

```css
body {
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink' width='100' height='40'%3E%3Cpath xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' d='M0,0h1v1H0' fill='%23008000'/%3E%3C/svg%3E");
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

Maybe there is a JavaScript solution to solve this problem?
It is also important that I can set the margin dynamically, so adding a border to the image does not work for me. 
Thank you!

Comment: I made an edit to the question to fix the url and to show the preview. Is that what you want? If so, then the answer is that your background image code was wrong. When you want to use svg as a data-uri image, you need to html encode entities.

Comment: Using CSS Background – Clip Property and setting it to padding box allows for a border. This can be done on floating div's therefore allowing an easy margin change. I'll be able to post more full answer later.

Answer (score 0):

One solution using `element()` but the support is still very low. The trick is to create and basic div with an image inside that you use as a background pattern then you simply adjust the padding inside that div.

Here is an example that works only on Firefox:

```css
#image {
  padding: 0 10px 15px 0; /* control the gap here */
  display:inline-block;
}

.main {
  height: 100vh;
  background: -moz-element(#image) 0 0/200px auto;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">

</div>


<div style="height:0;overflow:hidden;">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1024/300/300">
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Background pattern with fixed distance]

Width SVG you can try like below:

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bgimg" x="0" y="0" width="120" height="130"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1055/100/100.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10000" height="10000" fill="url(#bgimg)" />
</svg>
```

You simply need to control the width/height of the pattern element to control the distance. In the above we have a `100x100` image inside a `120x130` rectangle so a distance of `20` and `30` between each image

An Interactive example:

```js
$("#x").on("change", function() {
  $('#bgimg').attr("width",100+parseInt($(this).val()))
});

$("#y").on("change", function() {
  $('#bgimg').attr("height",100+parseInt($(this).val()))
});
```

```css
svg {
  position: fixed;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <pattern id="bgimg" x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100"  patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1055/100/100.jpg" x="0" y="0" height="100" width="100" />
    </pattern>
  </defs>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="10000" height="10000" fill="url(#bgimg)" />
</svg>


<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" id="x" value="0">
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="5" id="y" value="0">
```

Answer (score -1):

I have come up with a working and really simple solution.
The first thing is this, you do not need to add a margin for the repeating background.

### Trick

You can create a **margin** by adding a **border** to your background image, which you want to repeat. The **color of the border** will be the same as the parent background. So the border will not be visible and your desired results will be achieved.

```css
body {
  background: #f00 url("https://www.pngitem.com/pimgs/m/7-70908_square-shadow-border-white-vector-lines-edit-square.png"); 
  background-size: 50px 100px; 
  position: fixed;
  padding: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Hello World!</h1>
<p>W3Schools background image example.</p>
<p>The background image is only showing once, but it is disturbing the reader!</p>
```

[image]

Learn more about [CSS background-repeat property](https://www.tutsinsider.com/css/css-background/#3).

Comment: Unfortunately I need to be able to change this spacing later on in JavaScript, so this is no valid solution to my problem.